# disable swiftUI list row with original foreground colour or original rendering mode

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

[image]

Above is a list cell with `.disabled(amount == 100)` modifier

i want the same disabled list cell with original foreground color like below image
can anyone help me out Thanks in advance
[image]

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Items")) {
                    ForEach(paymentViewModel.listOfItems) { item  in
                        ZStack{
                            NavigationLink(destination: getDestination(item: item)) {
                                if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                                    PaymentOverviewCell(item: item)
                                        .padding(.top, 8)
                                } else {
                                    PaymentOverViewCell2(item: item)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .deleteDisabled(item.type == .service)
                        .disabled(item.type == .service) // here service should not be faded out
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: paymentViewModel.removeItemFromList)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.inset)
            Spacer()
            footer
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Payment")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
```

Comment: I believe you have to create your own ButtonStyle for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61986229/780291.

Comment: To "disable" from what? Please provide more details and code for demo and test.

Comment: its like first item in list should not be clickable and swipeToDelete able rest all items can swipe to delete and clickable using navigationLink @Asperi can you please check now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i found one answer

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Items")) {
                    ForEach(paymentViewModel.listOfItems) { item  in
                        ZStack{
                            // if service then don't embed in navigation link
                            if item.type == .service {
                                PaymentOverViewCell2(item: item)
                                    .padding(.top, 8)
                            } else {
                                NavigationLink(destination: getDestination(item: item)) {
                                    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                                        PaymentOverviewCell(item: item)
                                            .padding(.top, 8)
                                    } else {
                                        PaymentOverViewCell2(item: item)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .deleteDisabled(item.type == .service)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: paymentViewModel.removeItemFromList)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(.inset)
            Spacer()
            footer
                .padding()
        }
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .navigationTitle("Payment")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: btnBack)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).